# A number when divided successively by $5$ and $7$ leaves remainders $2$ and $4$ respectively. When it is divided by $35$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A number when divided successively by $5$ and $7$ leaves remainders $2$ and $4$ respectively. When it is divided by $35$?

What I did:-

$N=5a+2$,
$N=7b+4$

$$N=35c+d$$

Now how to calculate $a,b,c$ and $d$? Is there any approach to do this question?

Comment: Are you aware of modulo arithmetic?

Answer (score 2):

$$N=5(a+1)-3$$

and $$N=7(b+1)-3$$

So, $N+3$ is divisible by lcm $(5,7)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Didn't understand@labbhattacharjee

Comment: @SakuziMarkel, Observe that $N+3$ is divisible by $5$ and $7$

Comment: answer is 22 but @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @Sakuzi, $$-3=35-3=?$$

Comment: 32 @labbhattacharjee

Comment: but the answer is 22 not 32 @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @SakuziMarkel Take $67$ you have $67\equiv 2 \mod 5;\;67\equiv 4 \mod 7;\;67\equiv -3 \mod 35$ that is $67=35\times 1 +32$ there is no way the result is $22$